# reset() of Reader in zxing - android

Tags: android, zxing

I'm looking the zxing repository at GitHub for hours. The `BenchmarkAsyncTask` of `androidtest` walk throught a file path and continuously decode some image files wihout call `reset()` of the `reader`.

But in the comment of Reader.reset, it says that

> Resets any internal state the implementation has after a decode, to prepare it
>   for reuse.

Since we reused the `multiFormatReader`, should do not we call the `reset()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you debug the ZXing source code step by step, you will see that reset() does nothing for all readers except **RSS14Reader** and **RSSExpandedReader**.

Do nothing:

```
@Override
  public void reset() {
    // do nothing
  }
```

RSS14Reader.reset():

```
@Override
  public void reset() {
    possibleLeftPairs.clear();
    possibleRightPairs.clear();
  }
```

RSSExpandedReader.reset()

```
@Override
  public void reset() {
    this.pairs.clear();
    this.rows.clear();
  }
```

If you just want to read QR code, there's no difference. For example:

```
String[] fileNames = new String[]{"qrcode-1.jpg", "qrcode-2.jpg"};
File file = null;
BufferedImage image = null;
RGBLuminanceSource source = null;
BinaryBitmap bitmap = null;
Result result = null;
MultiFormatReader reader = new MultiFormatReader();

try {
    for (String fileName : fileNames) {
        file = new File(fileName);
        image = ImageIO.read(file);
        System.out.println(image.getWidth() + ", " + image.getHeight());
        int[] pixels = image.getRGB(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null, 0, image.getWidth());
        source = new RGBLuminanceSource(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), pixels);
        bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
        result = reader.decode(bitmap);
        System.out.println(result.getText());
        //reader.reset();
    }
}
catch (Exception exception) {
    System.out.println(exception);
}
```